# How to use ubuntu-terminal-app from unity8 on ubuntu 17.04 with unity7

Tags: unity, gnome-terminal, 17.04, unity8

That is pretty much it.

I've installed Ubuntu 17.04 but Unity 8 works horribly. The terminal app there  is awesome though and I would like to have it but on unity 7, is there a way?